# Surinder Singh still viable route for UK

Tags: immigration, surinder-singh

I am a retired UK citizen with adequate pensions and investments, my wife is a US citizen. We wish to spend half the year in the US and half in the UK. The UK right of residence procedure would appear to prevent this.
Could using the S.S. route through, say, Germany, give my wife freedom of movement between the UK and US without breeching her UK residency? Brexit permitting!

Comment: No one knows whether the Surinder Singh route will be viable. It depends on whether the Brexit "deal" passes parliament, and how the government interprets the law during the transition period. This question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Is your wife now in the UK?  If so, what is her status?  A UK standard visitor visa is valid for six months, and a US citizen admitted to the UK without a visa is normally admitted for six months.  Your wife could therefore, in theory at least, spend half of every year in the UK without needing any visa at all.  If you want to pursue a Surinder Singh application, though, it may be too late to establish yourself in Germany.  It's not clear to me that it would be possible after March 2019.

Comment: She is in the US, would travel to the UK on a visitor's visa. I assume the Surinder Singh route would be a possibility only if Brexit was cancelled by referendum. It appears to be impossible to have completely free travel between the US and UK util we acquire dual nationality, a long process.